# Command delegate parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Why am I not receiving the parameter into my delegate command? I've been stock on this issue for a couple of days now, but still cant get my head around it, I'm relatively new to the .NET framework. I am using MVVM and a command delegate to get x and Y coordinates of the click button   shape like a circle. However, my keeps on failing. Please, help me with this if possible. 
this is my view

```
<Button Width="20" 
        Height="20" 
        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.touchCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```

this is my view model

```
public  class ViewModel :  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region constructor plus member val
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<CartesianPoint> points { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CartesianPoint> missPoints { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand<CartesianPoint> SelectCommand { get; set; }
    public CartesianPoint SelectedPoint { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {

        points = new ObservableCollection<CartesianPoint>();
        missPoints = new ObservableCollection<CartesianPoint>();

        this.testData();
    }

    private void InitializeCommands()
    {
        SelectCommand = new DelegateCommand<CartesianPoint>( (p) => SelectedPoint = p );

    }
    #endregion constructor plus member val


    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if( PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        Console.WriteLine( "from on propertity change");

    }

    public ICommand touchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectCommand == null)
            {
                SelectCommand = new DelegateCommand<CartesianPoint>(( p) => Executed( p));

            }
            return SelectCommand;
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void Executed(object sender)
    {

        if (sender != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this is a test");
            CartesianPoint  input = sender as CartesianPoint;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}"input.X, input.Y);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't specified the `CommandParameter` value.

Comment: I had added it but it keeps on complaing. This is what I added CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=drilable,Path=Source}

Comment: @JoseGonzalez And you're hoping somebody on the internet has seen your XAML file, and knows what `drilable` is.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you for you for your demeaning massage you are very helpfull, Before down voting my question did you stop to think that XAML was large I might have been trying to void giving to much noise? Again Thank you!

Comment: @JoseGonzalez Did you stop to think that nobody can guess what's wrong with your code if you refuse to tell us what your code is?

Comment: What about a heads up? I understand I am the newbie here, and that I am asking for help, but when I for formulated the question I did not dim that section necessary, yes It is an overside on my part, but pointing(decently), that you dont understand a reference should be enough for me to correct the issue.

Comment: @JoseGonzalez OK, point made. Now kindly show us enough XAML to fully understand what `drilable` is, and what its `Source` property might be, and how all of that relates to your Button. Don't try to make me fight a battle with you for every tiny piece of information. Try to be a willing participant in the process. Help me to help you.

Comment: @JoseGonzalez Ed wants to help you -- he's all over WPF questions. I'm willing to bet that if you updated your question and included only the relevant portion of XAML (not the entire file), he'd even back out any downvotes ....but, I'm not him :)

Comment: @EdPlunkett Speaking of which, why don't you hang out in the [WPF Chat Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf), man? :)

Comment: @JoseGonzalez Lynn says "only the relevant portion of XAML", but if you knew precisely what's relevant, you wouldn't be stuck talking to me. When in doubt, include more.